# Linux Mint 18.1 only has 4GB RAM avilable, but 8GB are recognized

Tags: linux-kernel, hardware, ram

[repost from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875853/linux-mint-18-1-only-has-4gb-ram-avilable-but-8gb-are-recognized ]

the title pretty much sums it up. I have 5x2GB DDR3 RAM sticks available, and my motherboard has 4 slots (ASRock 907M Pro3). no matter which combination of RAM sticks I try, my system only uses 4GB total:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        4017860 kB
MemFree:         1587836 kB
MemAvailable:    2353096 kB
...
```

however: the BIOS shows all 4 sticks, as does `lshw`:

```
$ sudo lshw | grep -m 1 -A 46 "*-memory"
 *-memory
      Beschreibung: Systemspeicher
      Physische ID: d
      Steckplatz: Systemplatine oder Hauptplatine
      Größe: 8GiB
    *-bank:0
         Beschreibung: DIMM DDR3 Synchron 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
         Produkt: F3-10666CL9-2GBNQ
         Hersteller: Undefined
         Physische ID: 0
         Seriennummer: 00000000
         Steckplatz: A1_DIMM0
         Größe: 2GiB
         Breite: 64 bits
         Takt: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:1
         Beschreibung: DIMM DDR3 Synchron 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
         Produkt: CL6-6-6 DDR3-1333
         Hersteller: Undefined
         Physische ID: 1
         Seriennummer: 00000000
         Steckplatz: A1_DIMM1
         Größe: 2GiB
         Breite: 64 bits
         Takt: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:2
         Beschreibung: DIMM DDR3 Synchron 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
         Produkt: F3-10666CL9-2GBNQ
         Hersteller: Undefined
         Physische ID: 2
         Seriennummer: 00000000
         Steckplatz: A1_DIMM2
         Größe: 2GiB
         Breite: 64 bits
         Takt: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:3
         Beschreibung: DIMM DDR3 Synchron 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
         Produkt: CL6-6-6 DDR3-1333
         Hersteller: Undefined
         Physische ID: 3
         Seriennummer: 00000000
         Steckplatz: A1_DIMM3
         Größe: 2GiB
         Breite: 64 bits
         Takt: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
```

(sorry for german output, but I think you can figure out the meaning pretty easily)

**edit:** also, i found this in dmesg, not sure if it's related:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i -A 20  aperture 
[    0.000000] AGP: Checking aperture...
[    0.000000] AGP: No AGP bridge found
[    0.000000] AGP: Node 0: aperture [bus addr 0x6d08000000-0x6d09ffffff] (32MB)
[    0.000000] Aperture beyond 4GB. Ignoring.
[    0.000000] AGP: Your BIOS doesn't leave an aperture memory hole
[    0.000000] AGP: Please enable the IOMMU option in the BIOS setup
[    0.000000] AGP: This costs you 64MB of RAM
[    0.000000] AGP: Mapping aperture over RAM [mem 0xb4000000-0xb7ffffff] (65536KB)
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb4000000-0xb7ffffff]
[    0.000000] Memory: 3907664K/4166000K available (8829K kernel code, 1441K rwdata, 3832K rodata, 1548K init, 1296K bss, 258336K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

i enabled IOMMU (in the north bridge configuration, does something RAM-related belong there?), but nothing changed, the error still occurs. UEFI version is already the latest one (1.60).

**I tried the following:**

- read dozens of forum posts (most come up with the "old" suggestion to
  install a pae or highmemory kernel)
- recompile a kernel (4.8.0-41)
- recombine the RAM sticks in different ways
- search in my UEFI setup for any kind of setting
- check for correct RAM frequencies etc.

-> no reaction at all.

**things you should know:**

- my system is Linux Mint 18.1 Serena 64bit, KDE Edition (the issue appears on MATE Edition, too):

  ```
  $ uname -a
  Linux florian-desktop 4.8.0-42-generic #45~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 9 14:10:58 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- my kernel is v4.8.0-42, (the issue appears on older kernels, too)
- my kernel has PAE enabled and my cpu (FX-8350) supports it:

  ```
  $ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep pae
  flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate vmmcall bmi1 arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold
  ```

any idea what could cause this?

Comment: The leading cause would be that you're actually running a 32bit kernel.  Can you show us `uname -a`?

Comment: @JuliePelletier that might not explain everything; a PAE kernel is no doubt 32-bit but it should report all 8GB in `/proc/meminfo` (after all, the point of PAE is to be able to use more than 4GB in a 32-bit system).

Comment: @StephenKitt:  At this point, we don't even know if the CPU supports PAE.  OP mentions running a 64 bit installation which is what prompted my question.

Comment: Please don't cross-post. If you want to ask here and not on [so] (which you should, this isn't on topic for [so]), then delete your question on [so].

Comment: i'm in my mobile right now, so i can't show any code snippets (nor Tag anyone), but uname -a clearly days "x86_64".
the CPU itself is an fx-8350 - i Don't habe exact info wether it supports PAE, but pae is flagged in proc/cpuinfo, so i assume it does. 
i will add this info to my question tomorrow, when  i'm in my desktop again. also, i already flagged my post in stackoverflow as offtopic, it should be closed by now.

Comment: i apologize for the typos and missing tags. info is now added to the post.
@JuliePelletier

Comment: If it's not already, enable the BIOS options to view the BIOS POST and validate the amount of memory shown there.  If possible, it would be nice to try another OS to see if more is detected.  Another thing I'd try is to take out the last 2 DIMMs (banks 2 and 3) to see the impact on what is detected.

Comment: @JuliePelletier sadly, i cannot see any POST messages, i immediately get into GRUB after the setup prompt. 
one thing i found interesting is that (no matter what combinations i use), my BIOS always say "Single Channel Mode", never Dual Channel. Could this be the cause? Right now i have 3 2x2GB DDR3-1333 Kits available for testing, memtest says they are all fine, but no combination was working. i also tried to give more power to the north bridge and looked into the DDRAM settings in the BIOS, but so far no result. i'll try a different OS tomorrow.

Comment: Did you try it to see how much would be detected by removing banks 2 and 3 from your initial setup?  That should point you in the right direction.